# Como mostrar mensagem de validação abaixo de um grupo de botões radio?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Para o problema abaixo considere que estou utilizando Laravel (5.6* com arquivos de estilo e javascript default (sem alterações).

Meu problema esta basicamente ao tentar exibir a mensagem de validação do grupo de campos **radio** (id: genero), estes estão agrupados em um **fieldset**. A validação ocorre e no HTML (DOM) retornado consigo ver a mensagem presente, porém, ela não esta sendo exibida na tela.

Controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|min:3',
    'profissao' => 'min:3',
    'biografia' => 'min:20',
    'genero' => 'required|in:F,M,Não declarado',
    'data_nascimento' => 'required'
]);

//...
```

View:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('status') }}">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        {{ session('msg') }}
    </div>
@endif

<!-- //... -->

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="genero" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Gênero</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <fieldset id="genero">
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input{{ $errors->has('genero') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="genero" value="F" {{ $usuario->genero == 'F' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    Feminino
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input{{ $errors->has('genero') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="genero" value="M" {{ $usuario->genero == 'M' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    Masculino
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input{{ $errors->has('genero') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="genero" value="Não declarado" {{ $usuario->genero == 'Não declarado' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    Não declarado
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        @if ($errors->has('genero'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('genero') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pelas classes você está utilizando o Bootstrap, correto? A regra de validação desse parâmetro é feita com essa sintaxe: `.was-validated .form-control:invalid~.invalid-feedback`, então você precisa que o span de `invalid-feedback` seja o elemento seguinte do seu `form-control`. A documentação inteira tá aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: Obrigado, como somente esse form em especial possui os elementos citados, decidi fazer assim: ```<span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block !important;">```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na regra do próprio Bootstrap.
Pelas regras de sintaxe você deveria arrumar a disposição dos elementos na tela conforme [esta documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/).

Porém, como eu acredito que o seu layout já esteja definido, e você só renderiza o erro a partir do seu if do javascript, você pode sobrescrever a regra do seu `.invalid-feedback` adicionando isto no seu css:

```
.invalid-feedback {
    display: block
}
```

Desta forma o elemento sempre será visível, e a validação de se ele deve ser mostrado ou não será feita pelo seu `@if`.

Só tenha certeza que esse pedaço de código esteja abaixo da chamada do seu bootstrap.

Comment: Obrigado, como somente esse form em especial possui os elementos citados, decidi fazer assim: ```<span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block !important;">```, ou seja, utilizei sua sugestão diretamente no html